# Powershell implicit type conversion

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have the following powershell code, adding to a ArrayList.
When I ToString() and object and put its value in the list and later do a -join it comes out wrong.

```
$list =  New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList    
foreach($key in $keyList)
{
    $value = $dict[$key]

    $value.GetType() # Foo.Bar.SomeObject

    $stringValue = $value.ToString()
    $stringValue.GetType() # System.String
    $stringValue # Outputs the actual value eg. John Doe

    $list.Add($stringValue)
}

$list -join "," # Outputs Foo.Bar.SomeObject,Foo.Bar.SomeObject,Foo.Bar.SomeObject,Foo.Bar.SomeObject
```

Using `$list.Add("$value")` works fine. Causing `$list -join ","` to output the expected list of `John Doe,68,1292`

What is going on?

Comment: hows your sample list and what is that you are expecting ?

Comment: Can you modify the example to an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm working on it sorry. I thought i would just get it up without it if it was something obvious powershell magic going on. I will post a MVCE after lunch.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Don't be sorry :-) Unfortunately there is nothing obvious about the behavior you describe from the code you've posted so far

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i've looked at it some more I think I've been confused. The issue apparently .ToString() is not the same as simply outputing the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested in how you are defining `Foo.Bar.SomeObject`. I am pretty sure that the default implementation of `Object.ToString()` is to print out the type, as you are seeing, but then it is strange that the `"$value"` is working...

On a different note, you could clean up your code to be more PowerShell styled and it may help clear something up.

ToString:

```
$list = $keyList | ForEach-Object {$dict.$key.ToString()}
$list -join ','
```

String Format

```
$list = $keyList | ForEach-Object {"$($dict.$key)"}
$list -join ','
```

PowerShell works with strong types but you generally can write it without (one of its biggest advantages). Rarely do you need to explicitly call methods. If you are that concerned with the type you are using you can consider this instead:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$list = $keyList | ForEach-Object {"$($dict.$key)"}
$list -join ','
```